# Company or website logo as the search result image / Google+ profile

Tags: seo, google-search, google-plus

I was considering having for this website I'm working on, the website's logo as the image that gets included in the search results for the articles it publishes. So do to this I want to use Google Authorship with the business's Google+, but is this recommended? I ask because I've never seen an example where it was something other than the author's profile picture.

Comment: I'm not certain what you're asking. Do you want to use Google Authorship with your company G+ page?

Comment: @tinym Yes exactly, but also if it's recommended to use the google search results as a place to put a logo rather than a profile photo.

Comment: And why is this question closed? I was under the assumption that Pro Webmasters was the place for SEO related questions...

Comment: You don't mention SEO anywhere in the question.

Comment: @paulmorriss don't you think it's implied? Why else would I want to do this?

Comment: and even if I wanted to do this for reasons other than SEO, that doesn't make it any less off-topic either

Comment: Your question has been reopened. While I believe managing a company's larger internet presence falls *beyond* the scope of this site, SEO is explicitly on-topic. Your edits help make this question clearer.

Comment: @Aarthi thank you very much, I'll certainly bear that in mind for future questions

Comment: @Adam-E I think you might find the two answers on [this question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/how-to-display-an-image-in-google-search-result) helpful. They should answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing (authorship) is intended for personal G+ accounts... business's should be using pages. You are able to link your business page with your website so that it shows us on the *right* hand side of the search results, this however, isn't applied to each new article.

In my opinion I wouldn't use G+ personal pages for anything other than a personal page, stick to using it as Google intended, you might find yourself in a sticky situation down the line.

To have your logo show up on the *right* hand side of the search results you need to get your page verified by Google (http://support.google.com/plus/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=page_verification&rd=1) then link your site to the page using rel=publisher tag

Comment: Authorship could come in handy for the articles. Would set authors apart, and I believe that having the authors picture with the article increases the chances of the link getting clicked

Comment: Completely agree, but stick to using authorship as it was intended... for authors!