# How to display an image in google search result

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search

I managed to do it with [my blog](http://alfasin.com) like this:

[image]

by using google+ (found it somewhere on the web):

```
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/115170983146246266025/"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the way to display the "author" image, but what I want to do is display something like "product image", for example, for a food-blog, I'd like each recipe (post) to display the dish-image next to the search result.
I've got the feeling that there's a more generic way of doing it which doesn't rely on having a Google+ account. Any ideas ?

**UPDATE 2:**

I [added an example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/41074/13618) to what I meant in the answers section.

Answer (score 5):

[According](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) to Google

> If Google understands the content on your pages, we can create rich snippets—detailed information intended to help users with specific queries. For example, the snippet for a restaurant might show the average review and price range; the snippet for a recipe page might show the total preparation time, a photo, and the recipe’s review rating; and the snippet for a music album could list songs along with a link to play each song.

But Google doesn't guarantee showing rich snippets in your result. Additionally, you can check this [link](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1093493) for more information on rich snippets

**Answer to the question about authorship image, kept as some might find it useful**

Nope, you need to have a Google+ account in order for your image to show with search results for content you have authored. According to this [google support article](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1408986) there are two ways to do this -

1. The way you did it - Linking directly to your google+ profile
2. If you have an email id for the domain the content is posted on, like in your case *anything@alfasin.com*, you can add that email to your [authorship page](http://plus.google.com/authorship) and have a byline identifying your as the author(eg. *By Alfasin*) somewhere in the article.

But the prerequisite is that you have an Google+ profile, without that you can't have your picture shown in search results next to your content.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I remember seeing blogs with *different* images for different pages (don't remember where I saw it). Maybe it's a question of authority ?

Comment: Since different people can contribute can contribute to one blog/website, different images will appear for different pages of such sites. Just change the byline or G+ profile id to reflect the author and google will take care of the rest

Comment: It wasn't the case: it was a food blog and each post had it's "main image" as thumb on google search results page. If I'll find it I'll post it here.

Comment: But those aren't author images are they? They are images of the finished dish. You will get images with results if you search for recipes or food stuff. Also with news stories and stills of some videos. I don't know how to ensure your post gets it's image displayed next to the link, but you will need to post that picture with the article, so your picture in your blog post. But that won't ensure that it shows next to the result. I'm guessing it is an automatic thing that the algorithm does

Comment: you're right! that's not the author-image, it's more like "product-image". I'll update my question in regards - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found a good example:

[image]

And I suspect that this is how it's done:

[image]

but I'm not sure yet. I'll test it and if it works - I'll update my answer here (it might take 2-3 days before Google re-crawl my website).

**UPDATE:**

Didn't work for me, my guess is that the website itself needs more authority before Google picks up the "product image" as well as the author image. I'll try to send this question to Matt Cutts.

Comment: hey, did it work?

Comment: @elssar unfortunately not... I suspect that Google is taking the "product image" only for web-sites with high rank/authority. I wish someone in Google would answer that (I can keep dreaming, I guess...)

Comment: I think it checks whether it is a news story, or something with a rating, and that a picture would be better than text for the result.

Comment: @elssar it totally makes sense, too bad we can't validate it :)

Comment: I think [this](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99170) should clear up things a bit

Comment: I tried using microdata (schema.org) too - also didn't work... if you'll checkout my blog's HTML source you'll see stuff like `itemscope='itemscope' itemtype='http://schema.org/Blog'` etc

Comment: Like the link says, Google doesn't guarantee they'll show your microdata in search results. Check out the updated answer

Comment: I guess we'll never know the answer, unless Matt Cutts will say something in regards on his video-blog